# Sin regression pseudocode

Tags: c++, struct, analytics, regression, pseudocode

I was wondering that given an array that contains structs of ints x, and y what would be the pseudocode for for Sin regression? I have searched a while and google and I have no results so far.

Comment: That must be 'Sinusoidal Regression' or 'Sine Regression' :)

Answer (score 0):

This website may help you out.  They discuss how TI calculators perform sine regression.

[Algorithm Used for Calculating the Sine Regression](http://epsstore.ti.com/OA_HTML/csksxvm.jsp?nSetNumber=11576)